# Stochastic process with Student's t-distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I have encountered the following SDE $$dX_t=-X_tdt+\sqrt{1+X_t^2}dW_t.$$
Does anyone know a name by which the resulting process $X_t$ is commonly referred to? In the place I found it, it is claimed that $X_t$ is t-distributed for any $t\geq0$. It is also featured as an example on the following Mathematica documentation page:
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ItoProcess.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Leonenko and Šuvak](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07362994.2010.515476) call it *Student diffusion process*. Not too "common", but there's no other name I am aware of.

Answer (score 2):

It's not far off from the Hyperbolic diffusion:

$$dX_t = \alpha \frac{X_t}{\sqrt{1+X_t^2}}dt + \sigma dW_t$$ [ cf. [Parameter Estimation in Stochastic Diffential Equations](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-540-74448-1), page 2 or example 2.6 on page 47]

The example the author gives is as follows

$$dX_t = -\theta \frac{X_t}{\sqrt{1+X_t^2}}dt + \sigma dW_t$$
where $\theta \in (\alpha,\beta), \alpha>0$.